# Android - Firebase sign in using Microsoft

Tags: android, firebase, oauth-2.0, firebase-authentication, microsoft-graph-api

I'm integrating Firebase sign-in into an Android app, and using [Microsoft as a provider](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/microsoft-oauth)

when sign-in is successful, I get a [`OAuthCredential`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/OAuthCredential) object with which I can perform Graph API calls on behalf of the user.

the problem is that when requesting a [`offline_access`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-permissions-and-consent#offline_access) scope, I can't find the refresh_token i'm supposed to receive, as the [`OAuthCredential`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/OAuthCredential) object does not specify one.

My goal is to keep sending Graph API requests without prompting the users to re-sign in to their Microsoft account. (otherwise this feature does not seem very useful..)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firebase Auth does not return OAuth refresh tokens on sign-in. They will discard it after sign in completion. It is not secure for them to return it to the client anyway.

If it is a requirement for your application, you may need to trigger the Microsoft sign in flow separately. You can then use [custom auth](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/custom-auth) to sign in the user to Firebase.